# Dealing with dependent objects in Django templates

Tags: django, python-3.x

First of all, am I right in understanding that Django tags are effectively a mini-language unto themselves, and that Python won't run in them?

If so, how should I deal with values that would be difficult for the view to preprocess? For eg, this is what I want to do (a user has many ratings):

```
{% for user in users %} # Where users are defined in the view/context
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

Then inside that I've tried a couple of things

```
  {% for rating in user.ratings %}
```

or

```
  {% for rating in Rating.objects.filter(user=user) %}
```

The former never iterates. The latter is hideous, and in any case doesn't work - it raises `TemplateSyntaxError at / Could not parse the remainder`

But since it's only in the middle of the loop through users that I get the relevant user to filter by, I'm not sure how I would set up the second QuerySet in the view.

What's the best approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that you cannot run arbitrary Python in a template: the syntax is defined by the template system, which is by default the [Django template language (DTL)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/).

In your specific case, there is an easy way to access the foreign key relations of a model object: use the `_set` keyword. The following should work:

```
{% for rating in user.rating_set.all %}
<!-- do stuff with rating -->
{% endfor %}
```

By searching for just `item.ratings`, it is expecting `ratings` to be a model field. You need to specify `_set` to direct it to look at foreign key models.

This case is easy: in other instances, the best option is to run the logic in the view and pass the variable to the template's context or (non-trivial) to make your own custom template tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `_set.all`

```
{% for user in users %} # Where users are defined in the view/context
    {% for rating in user.rating_set.all %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you have to filtering [see this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/451).